# how to use datetime minvalue in get/set method when null is the database value

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two functions, in my constructor I read from the database and call all of my set functions:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Status = reader["status"].ToString();
    Event_Start_Date1 = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("event_start_date1"));
}
```

my get and set method for status works fine. for the date field however, i get an error because sometimes the field coming from the database is a NULL value. how would i modify my method to assign the minvalue incase the database returns a NULL?

```
public DateTime Event_Start_Date1
{
    get
    { return event_start_date1; }
    set
    { event_start_date1 = value; }
}
```

Comment: Use a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataReader.IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to check if the value is null:

```
Event_Start_Date1 = reader.IsDBNull("event_start_date1") ? DateTime.MinValue : 
reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("event_start_date1"));
```

The above sentence is in the following format:

> Condition ? accepted action : rejected
>   action

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the logic in a method:

```
private static DateTime GetDateTimeValue(SqlDataReader reader, string fieldName)
{
    int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
    return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? reader.GetDateTime(ordinal) : DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

...and call it:

```
Event_Start_Date1 = GetDateTimeValue(reader, "event_start_date1");
```

A more general and reusable approach could be to make it into an extension method that can (optionally) take a default value as input:

```
public static class SqlDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static DateTime GetDateTimeValue(this SqlDataReader reader, 
        string fieldName)
    {
        return GetDateTimeValue(reader, fieldName, DateTime.MinValue);
    }

    public static DateTime GetDateTimeValue(this SqlDataReader reader, 
        string fieldName, DateTime defaultValue)
    {
        int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) 
            ? reader.GetDateTime(ordinal) 
            : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

This assumes that you cannot change the model. If you have that option, go with a `Nullable<DateTime>` instead, and have the `GetDateTimeValue` method default to returning `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Check for DBNull and based on that you can assign MinValue.

```
int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("event_start_date1");
Event_Start_Date1 = reader.IsDBNull(ordinal)? DateTime.MinValue: reader.GetDateTime(ordinal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a nullable DateTime:

```
public DateTime? EventStartDate { get; set; }
```

Which is similar to:

```
public Nullable<DateTime> EventStartDate { get; set; }
```

[Read more about Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

To get the default value of DateTime, you can use either `DateTime.MinValue` or `default(DateTime)`:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Status = reader["status"].ToString();
    var startDate = reader.GetOrdinal("event_start_date1");
    EventStartDate = if reader.IsDBNull(startDate) ? 
                        reader.GetDateTime(ordinal) :
                        default(DateTime);
}
```

Essentially, `DateTime` is a [value-type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx), not a reference type, and there can't be a null `DateTime` (or whatever other [Value Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)) compile-time variable, in order for it to be capable to hold a null value it has to be wrapped in the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)).
In .NET all the non-nullable types have a default value which can be obtained via the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword (e.g. `default(DateTime)`).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `try-catch`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Status = reader["status"].ToString();
    try{
    Event_Start_Date1 = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("event_start_date1"));
    }
catch{
    Event_Start_Date1 = //some other thing
}
```

or you can use `GetSqlDateTime()`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Status = reader["status"].ToString();
    Event_Start_Date1 = reader.GetSqlDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("event_start_date1"));
}
```